# param is missing or the value is empty: user when tring to add a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I know this has been asked many  times but none of those could help me.

I'm building an online clinic website based on ruby on rails.
When a user wants to sign up it chooses either Doctor or  Patient. After that a sign-in form appears.
In DB, there's a general table for users for common attributes like name, gender etc. In that table the user type in set. For Doctor and Patient there are two separate tables for their specific attributes.
Here's the problem!
When signing up I get the error: raise ParameterMissing.new(key)

Here's thee code for doctor_controller.rb:

```
class DoctorsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_doctor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
#before_save :set_type
# GET /doctors
# GET /doctors.json
def index
  @doctors = Doctor.all
end

# GET /doctors/1
# GET /doctors/1.json
def show
end

# GET /doctors/new
def new 
  @doctor = Doctor.new
  @user=User.new
  @user.user_type='2'
end

# GET /doctors/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /doctors
# POST /doctors.json
def create

  @user=User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Doctor was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @doctor }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

@doctor = Doctor.new(doctor_params)


respond_to do |format|
  if @doctor.save
    format.html { redirect_to @doctor, notice: 'Doctor was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @doctor }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @doctor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /doctors/1
# PATCH/PUT /doctors/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @doctor.update(doctor_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @doctor, notice: 'Doctor was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @doctor }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @doctor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /doctors/1
# DELETE /doctors/1.json
def destroy
  @doctor.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to doctors_url, notice: 'Doctor was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_doctor
    @doctor = Doctor.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def set_type
    @user.user_type="2"
  end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def doctor_params
    params.require(:doctor).permit(:user_id, :doctroNum, :adderess, :sepciality, :records)
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_type, :username, :password, :name, :family, :gender, :phone, :city, :profilepicture)
  end

  end
```

and here is the code for signup form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :username, "Email" %><br>
  <%= f.email_field :username %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :family %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :family %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :gender %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :gender %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :phone %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :city %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :city %>
  </div>


  <% end %>

   <%= form_for(@doctor) do |f| %>
      <% if @doctor.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@doctor.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this doctor from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
         <% @doctor.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
         <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <% end %>

     <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :doctroNum %><br>
         <%= f.text_field :doctroNum %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :adderess %><br>
         <%= f.text_field :adderess %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :sepciality %><br>
         <%= f.text_field :sepciality %>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :records %><br>
         <%= f.text_field :records %>
     </div>
     <div class="actions">
         <%= f.submit %>
     </div>
    <% end %>
```

I know it's too much. I'd be really thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `f.submit` button for `form_for(@user)`, so whenever you press the submit button, the `form_for(@doctor)`'s submit button gets called. Hence, the `params` that are sent forward, always include `doctor`, and never include `user`. But the code in your `create` method expects `params` to have `user` in it: `@user = User.new(user_params)` - therefore, it is generating `param is missing or the value is empty: user`.

Apart from it, you are not following the good practices. You controller name is `DoctorsController`, but you are mixing it with the user's code. You should have two separate controllers: `DoctorsController`, `UsersController`, and accordingly two different views.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. I devided the tables for users and doctors and had an individual controller for each one of them.